# Replace $ in Stata variable labels with \textdollar

Tags: stata

I have some variables with dollar signs (i.e., `$`) in the variable labels. This causes some problems downstream in my code (I later modify these labels and the dollar signs deregister as empty global macros). So I would like to replace these dollar signs with LaTeX's `\textdollar` using Stata's `subinstr()` function.

But I can't figure it out. Is this possible? Or should I resign to doing this more manually? Or by looking for *other* characters near or around the `$` in the variable labels?

```
clear
set obs 10
generate x = runiform()
label variable x "Label with $mil"
generate y = runiform()
label variable y "Another label with $mil"

describe
foreach v of varlist * {
    local name : variable label `v'
    local name `=subinstr("`name'", "$mil", "\textdollar", .)'
    label variable `v' "`name'"
}
describe
```

This removes the label altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The problem has completely changed, which is why I give a separate answer.)

Having `$something` in the variable label is somewhat problematic because Stata will treat it as a `macro` and will therefore dereference it. What is actually Stata doing in your toy example? Let's see:

This is expected behavior:

```
. local name = subinstr("some text", " ", "xyz", .)

. display "`name'"
somexyztext
```

The following, which I don't know if documented, is not necessarily expected but crucial in understanding:

```
. local name = subinstr("some text", "", "xyz", .)

. display "`name'"

. (blank)
```

I put in the last line to emphasize that the local `name` has nothing.

In your code Stata dereferences `$mil` to nothing (because it's not declared beforehand; it's not meant to, of course). In fact,

```
label variable x "Label with $mil"
```

does not hold what you intend. Rather you want to delay macro substitution with `\`:

```
label variable x "Label with \$mil"
```

For the other part, when  you run this

```
local name `=subinstr("`name'", "$mil", "\textdollar", .)'
```

it evaluates to

```
local name `=subinstr("`name'", "", "\textdollar", .)'
```

and the local `name` now holds nothing. That ends the story of why your code does what it does.

A solution might be:

```
clear

set obs 10

generate x = runiform()
label variable x "Label with \$mil"

generate y = runiform()
label variable y "Another \$mil"

describe

*-----

foreach v of varlist _all {

    local name : variable label `v'
    label variable `v' "`=subinstr("`name'\$mil", "\$mil", "\textdollar", .)'"
}

describe
```

but this only works if `$mil` is at the end of the label text. If it is in the middle somewhere, another strategy must be used.

All this on Stata 12.1.

Comment: I find in Stata 13.1 that `subinstr("some text", "", "xyz", .)` just evaluates to `some text`. The logic is that an empty string is not a substring of any string, or perhaps that it were so deemed you would have to insert `xyz` everywhere! That contradicts the report here.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Forgot to report : I'm on Stata 12.1.

Comment: Presumably, the original poster is also on something other than Stata 13.1, since he claims: "This removes the label altogether."

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Very clear. Thank you. My labels come pre-assigned as `$mil` without the escape, so I don't think I have any option to relabel programmatically.

Comment: You're welcome. Your labels don't have to come with the escape ``\``, but they are necessary in order to establish the toy example. Similarly for the loop: they are there so macro substitution doesn't take place. Stata will then understand that you refer to the text `$mil` and not the macro. See http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/backslashes-and-macros/.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an argument in `subinstr()`, what appears in `help` as `n`:

```
clear
set obs 10
generate x = runiform()
label variable x "Label with $"

local name: variable label x
local name = subinstr("`name'", "$", "\textdollar", .)

label variable x "`name'"

describe
```

Comment: Is there any reason this would work in my toy data, but not in my real data? In my real data it just removes the `$`.

Comment: OK, it is because my real labels have `$mil`, not just `$`, and makes a difference (in my real code I had the fourth term as `.`, so it wasn't that -- I made a transposition error in generating my toy example). I will update the question.